# VS 2010 Unit Test Wizard autogenerated class accessor not compiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, interface

Consider a *VS 2010* solution with a *class library* project we will name `ClassLibrary`. In this project we have the following types:

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public interface IFooable<T> where T : struct
    {
       T Foo(T value);
    }

    public struct Blah : IFooable<Blah>
    {
       public static Blah Foo(Blah blah1, Blah blah2)
       {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
       }

       Blah IFooable<Blah>.Foo(Blah value)
       {
           return Blah.Foo(this, value);
       }

       private void ForceBlahAccessorCreation()
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
```

}

Now I'm also adding a *test project* to the solution and I'm using the *Test Wizard* to create some plumbing for my unit tests. Among this plumbing, the wizard creates a useful `Blah_Accessor` type that will let me access private static and instance methods, fields, properties, etc. of `Blah` which is pretty handy.

The problem is that with the code shown above, when I try to build the test project I will get the following compilation time error:

> Method 'Foo' in type 'ClassLibrary.Blah_Accessor' from assembly 'ClassLibrary_Accessor, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

Huh?

Can somebody please tell me if this issue reproduces on their VS 2010 or in any other VS version and why its happening?

**UPDATE**: Ok, I was under the impression that having a static method and an explicitly implemented interface method with the same name (`Foo`) could be the issue, but that is not the case. I'm getting the error even if its only the explicitly implemented `IFooable.Foo` method.

What is even more bewildering, is that if I choose to explicitly implement an interface from the .NET Framework, I get no error:

```
public struct Blah : IEquatable<Blah>
{
    public static bool Equals(Blah blah1, Blah blah2)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void ForceBlahAccessorCreation()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool IEquatable<Blah>.Equals(Blah other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
} //THE SOLUTION WILL COMPILE FINE

public struct Blah : IFooable<Blah>
{
    Blah IFooable<Blah>.Foo(Blah value)
    {
        return Blah.Foo(this, value);
    }

    private void ForceBlahAccessorCreation()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
} //TEST PROJECT WILL FAIL TO COMPILE
```

Comment: Don't use accessors, they're deprecated in later versions of Visual Studio. You shouldn't be testing private methods, anyway.

Comment: @DanielMann In our particular scenario, we've inherited code that we can not refactor more than what's strictly necessary. We either test private methods or we commit suicide...:p There is some extremely complicated logic going on that invloves numerous private methods. We'd rather break it into the smallest unit tests possible to make sure everything is working well from bottom up. I had no idea accessors were deprecated in newer VS by the way.